# how to initialize a field in schema xsd

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, xml, xsd

I work on `XSD` Schema , I would initialize a field by the value of another field in the same table .

For example: I want to initialize the fields Libel by Cmaps LibelleC .

*Is what you can give me the structure ?*

Comment: Like this                                                                                                                    <xs:element name="document">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="d_int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="d_int" type="xs:int" default="-1"/>

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<xs:element name="d_int" type="xs:int" default="-1"/>
```